# How to display decorated text with an icon in Gmail Add-on?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

Earlier I used the below code for displaying a decorated text in Gmail Add-on but the same code is now showing only text without icon. Is there any new method or another way to achieve same functionality?

```js
var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
var section = CardService.newCardSection(); // Create a card section
var htmlContent = 'Add Card';
var decoratedText = CardService.newDecoratedText()
  .setText(htmlContent)
  .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("showFirstCard"))
  .setIconUrl("https://i.imgur.com/x5Mh3vL.png");

section.addWidget(decoratedText);

card.addSection(section);

return card.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

We had this same issue.

```
.addWidget()
.setIconUrl('url..')
```

Changes to

```
.addWidget()
.setStartIcon(
  CardService.newIconImage().setIconUrl('url..'),
)
```

Source:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-service

Also had to update

```
"@types/google-apps-script": "^1.0.82",
```